# cannot make an async function using sequelize

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get information from my model but it always returns me `Promise { <pending> }` or `undefined` (on all the ways I had tried)

Heres the code that I'm trying to use to retrieve information from DB

```
const cnabBody = require('../controller/cnabBody');

let resultado = cnabBody.encontrarUm().then((r) => {
    console.log(r);
});
```

Heres my controller

```
const CnabBody = require ('../model/cnabBody');

exports.encontrarUm = async () => {
    const { nome_campo } = await CnabBody.findOne({where:{nome_campo: "Nome do Campo"}});
    return nome_campo;
}
```

Comment: Change `const { nome_campo } = await CnabBody.findOne(...)` to `const nome_campo = await CnabBody.findOne(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling my `async` functions inside a function that wasnt `async` soo when i tried any `await` method it wasnt awaiting or returning a error soo i changed my first line
`wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function(){`
to
`wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(async function(){`

soo my code looks like this now and it is working fine. (:

```
wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(async function(){
    var sh = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    // console.log(sh.getCell("A1").value);

    const field = await cnabContent.findOne({where: {nome_campo: "Nome do Campos"}});
    console.log(field);
});
```

Thanks for all that tried to help me, made me do alot of searchs and read about promises, async and await and get this solution.

Comment: how is this code working fine?? you have used `await` and not used `async` in your function?

Comment: Thanks for notification, i forgot to write the `async` but it is in my function

Answer (score 1):

I would need to know more about the object structure that's resolved from the `findOne` function, but it sounds like the `nome_campo` object being returned is a `Promise` object rather than a value. If that's the case then you'd also have to `await` on the nome_campo (assuming it's not undefined).

If `CnabBody.findOne()` returns this:

```
{
  nome_campo: somePromise 
}
```

then you should either change `findOne` to await on that `Promise` and send back the object it resolves to, or you need to `await` on it after receiving it in your controller. The latter could be done like this:

```
const CnabBody = require ('../model/cnabBody');

exports.encontrarUm = async () => {
  const { nome_campo } = await CnabBody.findOne({where:{nome_campo: "Nome do Campo"}});
  if (nome_campo) return await nome_campo;  // <--- add await here if defined
}
```

However I'd say it's nicer if `findOne` could be changed (assuming you have access to the code) so that calling `await CnabBody.findOne()` returned the actual result and not a Promise. Having `Promise` that resolves another `Promise` seems redundant, but if you are not the author of `findOne` then you might not have the option to change its resolved object.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller change `const { nome_campo }` to `const nome_campo`. it will work

```
const CnabBody = require ('../model/cnabBody');

exports.encontrarUm = async () => {
   // const { nome_campo } = await CnabBody.findOne({where:{nome_campo: "Nome do Campo"}}); <== problem is here
      const nome_campo = await CnabBody.findOne({where:{nome_campo: "Nome do Campo"}}); 

    return nome_campo;
}
```